# Exception in document() function in xslt when using absolute path

Tags: xml, xslt

I am using absolute path to access a document in xslt.

```
 Example : document('file:///C:/learningxslt/examples/ch13/jonah1.xml').
```

Through an online source I got to know I can use absolute path in xslt..but when I am using it is giving me exception

```
ERROR:  'com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.WrappedRuntimeException...(system cannot find the file specified) TransformerException.
```

Could anyone please tell me how can i access a file through aboslute path? through doc() or document() function?.

Thanks.

Comment: This might not be related to your issue, but could help: https://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/158765-xpath-document-function-doesnt-support-absolute-filepaths

Comment: Sorry if the answer is patronising, but my instinct is to believe the error message: if it says the file doesn't exist, then it probably doesn't. It could of course be some other error like file permissions, or it could be that the error doesn't relate to this particular filename.